# Do you have an example git repository with impending non-trivial merge conflicts?

Tags: git, merge

I've gotten to the point with git that I feel like I know what I'm doing most of the time.  I've got local branches for working on features.  I rebase periodically and merge between my branches.. I'm slowly getting to the point where I'm *getting it*.

Until today when I ran into a situation where, during a rebase, git explained there were problems and asked me to fix things before --continue'ing.  I did my best, but it was definitely deeper water than I was used to swimming in.

While there are dozens of *"how do I resolve merge conflicts?*" questions, I'm actually looking for a publicly available git repository which is in the state where a merge or a rebase will result in a few *non trivial* known conflicts.  Something where I can play with **mergetool**, **rebase --continue**, etc.

Has anyone ever seen a tutorial like this?

Comment: For playing around like this, I usually just create a repo on github with a text file. Then I edit the file on github with the "edit this file" button, which will generate a new commit automatically. Then I also edit/commit some changes to my local copy. Then I play around with merging the two.

Answer (score 0):

non-trivial merges are best exemplified by doing a rebase where the two branches have diverged more and more. Each step in the rebase will be a pain and will be compounded in the next one you have to resolve. If you want to get some good practice with conflicts, try remerging feature branches into a release candidate branches in different configurations (leave one out one time, leave out another one the next time). Without rerere you'll be pulling your hair out resolving the same conflicts over and over. This is the power of git. You should be able to destroy a branch and rebuild it quickly. Hope this gives you a good challange. We've taken this to the extreme with this branch-per-feature workflow: https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR

Have fun! :)